# Connect to TIBCO EMS from AWS Lambda function (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, tibco-ems, ems

I need to create a **AWS lambda** function using **.NET core**.

The function should read messages from **TIBCO EMS**. What are the steps to be followed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Tibco EMS .Net client library. It was recently built to the .NET Standard 2.0 specification, according https://community.tibco.com/questions/net-standard-compliant-tibcoemsdll. I didn't find it on NuGet but maybe it's on Tibco Website.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS I think we don't have that option. But we have the same in Azure using Web jobs.

As a workaround

1. In the EC2 instance keep a Windows Service / Linux demon up and running it should continually listen to Tibbco EMS queues
2. Once we received any message directly post same to the lambda function for the further processing.

Answer (score 0):

To Answer to Lambda, I am looking for the same. I didn't found exact solution finally we are going with .NEt core worker server and deployed as Linux demon its continually getting message from there we will call AWS Lambda

We don't have a Nuget package for the Tibco EMS .NET library. to download please go with this below
you can go to:

https://www.tibco.com/products/tibco-messaging/downloads

and look for:

'TIBCO Enterprise Message Service™ - Community Edition – Free Download - Windows'

After installing the downloaded file:

TIB_ems-ce_8.x.x_win_x86_64.exe

to find an DLL go into bin folder there  u can find an dll